# How to put parameters in RESTful POST with JerseyFramework

Tags: java, jersey

Let's assume that I have simple class:

```
   public class Test
    {
       @Path("/test")
       @POST
       @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
       @Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
       public TestResponse post(TestResponse request, @HeaderParam("text") String text)
       {
          return new TestResponse(request.getData());
       }
    }
```

and I want to test this class. So how I can param in code like this:

```
 Entity<TestRequest> requestEntity = Entity.entity(request, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
 final TestResponse response =  target("test").request().post(requestEntity, TestResponse.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
target("test").request().header("text", "value").post(...);
```

When you call `request()`. You get back an [`Invocation.Builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html). You can take a look at the other methods. For the most part they all return the same `Invocation.Builder`, so can just chain the calls.

Comment: And what about @PathParam, there is method target("test").path("") but should I pass value in path("...") ?

Comment: If you have `@Path("/test/{something}")`, then just do `target("test").path("whatever")`. The value of `@PathParam("something") String something` will be `"whatever"`

Comment: If this method casts other types, for example int ?

Comment: Yeah, read the Javadoc for [`@PathParam`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html). It shows what types you can use. The third points basically is saying it will convert any primitive type.